# Puppeteer code doesn't work on Google Cloud Virtual Machines but works perfectly on local machine

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer

I recently started studying puppeteer, and to practice it I tried scraping [www.myntra.com](http://www.myntra.com) and the code was working fine on my local machine. I then decided to try and run it on a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud and initially it was working fine. Now after a couple of weeks, when I try running the code again on VM it doesn't load the website but the code still works as expected locally.

[This image is captured using page.screenshot command when being run on the VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRN8Y.png)

```
const myntra_url = 'https://www.myntra.com/'
async function openBrowser()
{
    //open browser
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });

    page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setUserAgent(
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'
    )  

    await page.goto(myntra_url);
    await page.screenshot({path: 'img.png', fullPage: true });
}
```

The above code snippet is what I used to capture the screenshot to check if the website was loading on Virtual Machines or not.

I also tried changing the IP of the Virtual Machine and even tried different providers like DigitalOcean and Hostinger

Edit: This is the HTTP response from the server while navigating using page.goto()

```
{ 'mime-version': '1.0',
  'content-length': '483',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  expires: '0',
  'content-type': 'text/html',
  server: 'Apache/2.4.1 (Unix)',
  date: 'Tue, 21 Dec 2021 05:53:33 GMT',
  'set-cookie':
   'AKA_A2=A; expires=Tue, 21-Dec-2021 06:53:33 GMT; path=/; domain=myntra.com; secure; HttpOnly\nakaas_myntra_SegmentationLabel=1642658013~rv=33~id=0e014616c2288ab0cbb4054d9cf995bb~rn=PWA; path=/; Expires=Thu, 20 Jan 2022 05:53:33 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None',
  'server-timing': 'cdn-cache; desc=HIT\nedge; dur=1',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15768000 ; includeSubDomains' }
```

Edit 2: This is the HTTP response while navigating using page.goto() when the code is run on my laptop

```
{
  'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
  etag: 'W/"2325a-ra/cTi3uexrVThqYp3VqutNXiQU"',
  'x-response-time': '21.313ms',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'x-akamai-transformed': '9 - 0 pmb=mTOE,4mRUM,3',
  date: 'Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:10:00 GMT',
  'set-cookie': '_d_id=b4998f50-5039-4f36-b284-8dbdd6250308; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 18 Sep 2024 07:10:00 GMT\n' +
    '_mxab_=checkout.selective%3Denabled%3Bconfig.bucket%3Dregular%3Bpdp.desktop.savedAddress%3Denabled%3Bcheckout.couponUpsell%3Denabled%3Bcheckout.cartLoginNudge%3Denabled%3Bcheckout.attachedProducts%3Denabled%3Bcheckout.cartMessaging%3Denabled%3Bcheckout.donation%3Denabled%3Bpdp.expiry.date%3Denabled%3Bcheckout.addressOnCart%3Denabled; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:40:00 GMT\n' +
    '_pv=default; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:15:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'dp=d; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:16:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'at=ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJbXRwWkNJNklqRWlMQ0owZVhBaU9pSktWMVFpZlEuZXlKdWFXUjRJam9pTlRkalpUQmtOekl0TmpOaVppMHhNV1ZqTFdJM1ltWXRNREF3WkROaFpqSTRZVFUzSWl3aVkybGtlQ0k2SW0xNWJuUnlZUzB3TW1RM1pHVmpOUzA0WVRBd0xUUmpOelF0T1dObU55MDVaRFl5WkdKbFlUVmxOakVpTENKaGNIQk9ZVzFsSWpvaWJYbHVkSEpoSWl3aWMzUnZjbVZKWkNJNklqSXlPVGNpTENKbGVIQWlPakUyTlRVM09UVTBNREFzSW1semN5STZJa2xFUlVFaWZRLmJCNmVNRlY0LUVTMVJuU1lpNDE4a2hodVN1M2V5d1lPYnlFZFotVjhBNE0=; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 27 Jun 2022 07:10:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'bc=true; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/\n' +
    'microsessid=573; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:40:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'utm_track_v1=%7B%22utm_source%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%22utm_medium%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%22trackstart%22%3A1640243400%2C%22trackend%22%3A1640243460%7D; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:11:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'lt_timeout=1; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:40:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'lt_session=1; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:40:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'utrid=uuid-16402434004707; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 21 Jun 2022 07:10:00 GMT; HttpOnly\n' +
    'user_session=-1J5ucA1ht4_PXossxy10g.-CMVetdEuZC-KGhpMzXY0gOJ7DR6jOXF9-rwK4YyzK65vBn0_7ISlEFLXJfAJv9qbLiOBwwZRJXoJ5HUZZgcv-aNSiD_LsY1FxrXFJnaApMRquj8rRSxdXXpYPOkKYGiGiONQSyWwf-4tEzMsnfolw.1640243400468.86400000.73IBy-RLTmo1rot2RsOfgTEIr5tJLeeT1_FyRMFRAqg; path=/; expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 07:20:00 GMT; domain=.myntra.com; httponly\n' +
    'AKA_A2=A; expires=Thu, 23-Dec-2021 08:10:00 GMT; path=/; domain=myntra.com; secure; HttpOnly\n' +
    'akaas_myntra_SegmentationLabel=1642835400~rv=60~id=0dc3e9a01677da83cf8b1359fe95e1b8~rn=PWA; path=/; Expires=Sat, 22 Jan 2022 07:10:00 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None\n' +
    'bm_mi=13A16C8EAD963EAA2178C4F10B835209~8jOw4j5/LNPx+Q64n4D1NoWnn3ANCmd7Z4xMfHjDxlyoP/0VmwnxNb8I9nFsRMJva9YZAPyEF1aU1RINWxx2r1u74EQK56d5hdLrTPpHAlpZ3ZBqyUfV9C3cGvIQAQlxzM1dK9yaq5zPp5JsEXcH9JLNWC/Bc++MAqDMi8jRsShFobMIBPVvpYwhVtLhb8xBg4PRZ69Y4I0ObztcinLxeQfilVz/zF/cekSRzHz46ZlCouyk5uwYJj/a3v2u5zNl; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Max-Age=0; HttpOnly\n' +
    '_abck=5FFD2B9DAA2A989A9E57E7E539BB9DE3~-1~YAAQpP3UF9mC2Mp9AQAAOQ8g5gfphOk+bERcC6JoVEJoqW71i3fgcSJL3yjDaOCCz45XCMVwKR04u27A3fhtRwARgb27lGA3/QM+wgjLqiVT+5zd7jsgyFLsy8S8Rve1bF6/VexmGC7Fn0QwqPJWBArDQJDZF0fyUoyNvpr3Guitxotxole3CD/MIkXU8IOgxuceFUADNoUIyGVqZ1XQh0RI8/b1sWw4hzRGU5rDB5QueIDisubwy9WRdsGilEuAfIDRBuetDb1GyOQ8/rwda1xNbv3Y4BDrAPuEawInhOcSoJbfksBLWXPU32dIGGbuk/HjmK08D6CO++iL5xIVKkj+Z6xDfeAjeJDrDc3mXdPFP+PUKO8LKSBfTbA=~-1~-1~-1; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 23 Dec 2022 07:10:00 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure\n' +
    'ak_bmsc=87F76D36C1615D7A6A6C701D5CBF81B2~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQpP3UF9qC2Mp9AQAAOQ8g5g6AXDGBK/udhQzN/jsXcOO/7g40KWGKMpeEfsBdLQLDk0O+nglUDKyLFmRwL79g7NRjo8QxCwHuUWSpk40pU1wVXuVnAshCXisFS3pa6HiIMBsUAj9qnwIKySTRl/C1HObUQreKDM0lFc0KMa/acDpZwj00mcz6IKbHw5sphcPSK7H0AFHPYf51HlcFrT42if6E/4tzdLp9tqSZglUIfZtwQpyUZK4PeuodafZWYNZ1oP+WQOIO36O6BkljvCxNoIYbzL6reY9MM1WAQKhQb5DscMMsnASqqSj6vB3gA2OVJzURiBNuODP+W85DKFK6kndlPIt/UaKMXiiwKC+9Xwy04HwmtQcktKYmyXsAlBIw33vG0Dg0; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 09:10:00 GMT; Max-Age=7200; HttpOnly\n' +
    'bm_sz=65769455C92599BAC6D7C6AA3AA996B6~YAAQpP3UF9uC2Mp9AQAAOQ8g5g4htUDLSyu98f+YExGJg9JPORO/I76qfr6lTo0eHrtHrC0rFq/hjeibhI1rKH2G4h58mEs/7cJotRBmtvPSaT1CDSz5B6kK+uiKumyeBhCzBOscwj/CCYsZojnQkHfVoZJ/bmV8cJ0M2fmjhY7Jzw7M6P9G90qMjxh5/+OOmlD0QcqOg4a6gxBFT3MFEFYQyHF6pDtL92DHqgAoKQJrblUZ0oFQLbu5L9TkD6atkzAZI3Zhqn5lAqT/K7AWKA3LRFXlWaatlvU6HPmTNO8O5yA=~3553605~4338245; Domain=.myntra.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 23 Dec 2021 11:10:00 GMT; Max-Age=14400',
  'server-timing': 'cdn-cache; desc=MISS\nedge; dur=61\norigin; dur=30',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15768000 ; includeSubDomains'
}
```

Comment: Please provide the HTTP response for `page.goto(myntra_url)`.

Comment: @AnthumChris I have updated the question with the HTTP response for page.goto(myntra_url). Please let me know if you what the issue is

Comment: What is the content of the response if I may ask?

Comment: @Vaviloff I have edited the post to add the HTTP response

Comment: `content-length': '483'` What is the *content* of that response? I bet they're saying "please solve a CAPTCHA" or something.

Comment: @vaviloff there doesn't seem to be any captcha thats required as there is no page that's loaded. I have updated the post again to include the HTTP response when I run the code on my laptop.

Comment: Found the content of that response, glanced over it the first time, sorry. It's actually the "Oops, something's wrong" page. I would suppose that the target site has IP ranges of major hosting providers blacklisted. Try using proxies or some smaller hosting providers.